# React TypeError undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, typeerror

I'm new in React world. I'm creating weather app and I'm using openweathermap api to get data (used dark sky api and had the same problem). 
The problem is that I get a fetch data and save it to state. I am able to print by JSX and console.log the whole content of that state but can't reach specific data inside (by console.log and JSX). 
The problem says:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined**

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TemperaturesList from './TemperaturesList';
import axios from 'axios';

class WeatherData extends React.Component {
    state = { weatherData: {}, error: null };

    componentDidMount(){

        axios.get('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${this.props.lat}&lon=${this.props.long}&appid=MYAPPID')
        .then(result => this.setState({
            weatherData: result
        }))
        .catch(error => this.setState({
            error: error
        }))

    }



    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            {JSON.stringify(this.state.weatherData)} // this works
            <h3>Current weather:</h3>
            {JSON.stringify(this.state.weatherData.data.city)} // this does not work
            </div>

        );
    };
};

export default WeatherData;
```

And here's what I get from fetch and save in state:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the data is being fetched from the server in `componentDidMount` React will try to render what is currently in the state:

```
state = { weatherData: {}, error: null };
....
{JSON.stringify(this.state.weatherData.data.city)}
```

where `weatherData` is an empty object at this point.

You could fix it by setting `data` in the state:

```
state = { weatherData: { data: {} }, error: null };
```

Answer (score 0):

The api call will be triggered after `render` and hence `this.state.weatherData.data` will be undefined on initial render. Also it is better to store the axios `response.data` in state rather than the whole response itself. This should work

```
import React from 'react';
import TemperaturesList from './TemperaturesList';
import axios from 'axios';

class WeatherData extends React.Component {
  state = { weatherData: {city: ''}, error: null };

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast? 
     lat=${this.props.lat}&lon=${this.props.long}&appid=MYAPPID')
    .then(result => this.setState({
        weatherData: result.data
    }))
    .catch(error => this.setState({
        error: error
    }))

}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.weatherData)}
        <h3>Current weather:</h3>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.weatherData.data.city)}
        </div>

    );
 };
 };

 export default WeatherData;
```

Comment: Thanks!  It's helpful!